# Select * to table where datetime is 24 hours ago

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select all data in table created not less than 24 hours ago. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do your records have a date created column?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your table has a DATETIME field, in this example called date_field

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date_field >= SUBDATE( NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date_field > NOW() - interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your database. Look up the date math  functions e.g. datediff and date_sub in your help files.

Comment: judging by the tags i think it's mysql